# named - High Memory Utilization

Tags: bind

I have a Ubuntu server with Bind9 installed and recently it start to utilize more than 95% of the available RAM.

When I restart the process RAM utilization is coming back to normal but after few hours it's utilizing the memory again.

Following are the logs I have took from the server

[free-m && htop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8W5lm.jpg)

**Server Spec.**
Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
4GB RAM

Bind version :- BIND 9.9.5

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your caching a lot of hosts.. Try to limit the amount of cache used via the following option

http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch7/hkpng.html#max-cache-size

Comment: Thanks for the reply....
Is there anyway that I can track " caching a lot of hosts " ?

Comment: yes look into `statistics-channels` in bind